# What is the "atom" data type?

Tags: c++, winapi, types

I have encountered the `ATOM` type in the [Win32api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and also in the Acrobat API there is [ASAtom](http://livedocs.adobe.com/pdfl_sdk/9/PDFL_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/AS_Layer/ASAtom.html).

As far as I can tell, atoms are keys for a hash table usually of strings to enable fast look up and share data between applications. Is this correct and what is the etymology of the atom type?

**EDIT**

After some extensive searching I noticed [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) uses atoms, so there must be some origin to this word. It seems it used to refer to any single piece of data.

Comment: Yes, there is an origin to the word. It comes from the Greek word *ἄτομος* (*atomos*), meaning *"indivisible"*. (tongue in cheek...)

Comment: I think X11 had the Atom concept too - to allow the client app to store a piece of data in the X server.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That helped out a lot, it would explain why an `ATOM` is defined as `typedef WORD ATOM` because a word is the addressable unit by the CPU (i.e. not divisible).

Comment: @JesseGood: Haha yes... except that it should probably instead be a larger type like `UINT_PTR`, since CPUs nowadays address 32-bit and 64-bit chunks. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: On Windows its defined as `unsigned short` (probably because it originated from 16-bit windows, but Acrobat API defines it as `unsigned long`.

Comment: It is not a hash table, it is a dictionary.  The atom is the key, a simple integral number to help deal with variable length data.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you sure? Quote from the link to MSDN in my question: `Atom tables are implemented as hash tables`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Aren't hashtables just one kind of dictionaries/maps? I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Erlang has atoms as well: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66276

Comment: seem very similar to Objective C's "selectors", which are interacted with through [`sel_registerName :: const char * -> SEL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418557-sel_registername?language=objc) and [`sel_getName :: SEL -> const char *`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418571-sel_getname?language=objc)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ATOM is a 16-bit Windows handle-like primitive. It's value is completely opaque to user-mode. It is not a pointer or an index.

typedef unsigned short ATOM;

Comment: I'm guessing they are generated using some internal hash function?

Comment: No. They are indexes into a handle table in kernel mode. They are deliberately opaque because leaking kernel mode pointers to user-mode is a security violation.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. It seems that windows uses atoms internally for efficiently storing and retrieving strings.

Comment: (I linked to the same site in my question)

Comment: @SecurityMatt: Shouldn't dereferencing a kernel mode pointer trig STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: @user877329: If you tried that from user mode, it would.  But even leaking the kernel addresses can be harmful, see attacks such as Spectre and Meltdown and Downfall.

Answer (score 11):

As for the etymology of the name `ATOM`, I know I've once seen it in some old Microsoft Win32 API documentation that it is an acronym of "**A**ccess **to** **M**emory" or something like that. It is a term used for simple numerical identifiers (other name is "handles") which represent some internal data structures in the system.

From obvious reasons, it wouldn't be smart to give the user direct pointers to these structures. First, because they reside in kernel space, and second, because it violates encapsulation. The user could then just free the memory which doesn't belong to it, or overwrite it, or some other stupid ideas. So the operating system simply gives it some replacement number tag (that's the ATOM), which then could be used to request the data from the system. It's also faster for the user to pass around the little number instead of the whole huge data structure. Users don't need to care about memory allocations & stuff, or accessing some data through pointers which are no longer valid, which could simply crash their programs.

Comment: *Users don't need to care about memory allocations...* You know that also ATOM tables have limits, this is especially true for the global atom table.

Comment: You've got me wrong. I was not talking about allocation *space*, but about allocation *method*. That is, users don't have to care about how to allocate memory for these objects and where, they don't need to deal with all the fuss of allocating, freeing, and checking for invalid pointers. But of course they still need to care about how much memory they allocate for their resources. But I thought this is obvious.

Comment: Yes, that's clear to both of us. Your answer still seems a little too optimistic. Why do you not just name the reduction of the most annoying aspects of memory management (ressource leaks, dangeling pointers)? The **allocation itself can fail**, and this of course has to be checked.

Comment: Sure, but as I said, those are the unimportant details which are irrelevant to the original question asked. Why to bother stating the obvious at all? If the original poster didn't asked about them, I assume he is smart and aware of these details. He only asks about what is ATOM. But if you think otherwise, why don't you add your own answer?

Comment: Ok. Your approach to this question was not easy to get for me, because I found it (the question) searching for the width of the ATOM type. (sure it's 16 bits, but on purpose? For all future? ... MS itself isn't clear about this)

Comment: The etymology is almost certainly a back formation. It comes from Lisp. Symbols are "atoms" in Lisp. When a symbol token is read by the Lisp reader, it becomes a character string which is immediately "interned": converted to a symbol.  Symbols can be compared as pointers: if a symbol A is equal to B, we know they are the same atom; we don't have to do a character-by-character comparison of their string names. In the X Windows system, converting a string to an `XAtom` is called `XInternAtom` using the "intern" terminology of Lisp. Windows probably cribbed "atom" it from there.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest thing I can find about the term "atom" is from the Lisp programming language ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)). However, it probably originally came from [mathematical logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_formula). In programming they are also called [Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28Lisp%29) and at its simplest form are name integers (an enumerated type in C would be an example). However, they are widely used in many programming languages and in the Win32 API and Acrobat API they are identifiers for strings in a table.

Also, as [Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525511/questions-about-atoms-and-atom-tables/10526830#comment13614818_10525511) points out, the original meaning in Greek is "indivisible", so they imply a primitive data type which cannot be broken down any further.

Comment: Which is why the name for an atom (the physics/chemistry thing) is arguably incorrect.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi we didnt know about it tho

Answer (score 2):

The **RegisterClass** / **RegistrClassEx** functions (and a few others) return an **ATOM** data type. 
The ATOM uniquely identifies the class being registered, but if the function fails it returns zero, so you can test if the function has failed like this

```
ATOM a=0;
.
.
a = RegisterClassEx(your_window);
if (0==a)
  {
    //code for function failed
  }
```

Comment: Can you name a few more functions that returna an ATOM?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible answer as included in chapter 3. of C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable Software. Written by David R. Hanson in 1997:

> Atom is a pointer to a unique, immutable sequence of zero or more
> arbitrary bytes. Most atoms are pointers to null-terminated strings,
> but a pointer to any sequence of bytes can be an atom. There is only a
> single occurrence of any atom, which is why it’s called an atom. Two
> atoms are identical if they point to the same location. Comparing two
> byte sequences for equality by simply comparing pointers is one of the
> advantages of atoms. Another advantage is that using atoms saves space
> because there’s only one occurrence of each sequence. Atoms are often
> used as keys in data structures that are indexed by sequences of
> arbitrary bytes instead of by integers. The tables and sets described
> in Chapters 8 and 9 are examples.